# HDFS showing heartbeat lost for nodes

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hdp

I am new to HDP sandbox. I installed HDP sandbox in the Virtual machine. After installation when I start http://localhost:1080 it connects to Ambari but here it shows alerts for errors. one such error is Connection failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused to sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:50010. none of the nodes are showing a heartbeat in Ambari.

Comment: HDP sandbox is deprecated, and shouldn't be used...

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox intentionally does not start any of the Hadoop services. Only the Ambari webserver and SSH server are started by default. You need to manually enable any other services, such as Namenode, Datanodes, YARN, HiveServer, etc.